# SHOW databases; - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL and I am trying to run my first line in SQL - of course the `SHOW databases;` However, it gives me the error message :

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'SHOW'.

But it seems like I can do `CREATE table Test2` just fine. I am confused, did I miss anything please

Thank you very much, appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry but MySQL and SQL Server are different products. You appear to be using the second one with documentation for the first one.

Comment: `show databases;` is MySQL. `EXEC sp_databases` is SQL Server as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It looks like you are using SQL Server.

Try using

        SELECT name
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

or 

    EXEC sp_databases

Comment: SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases